# Hc 06(bluetooth module) slows down when I send data

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I used wemos d1 mini to check this situation with Arduino IDE.

```cpp
double counter = 0;
double Setpoint;
String Signal;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available()>0) {
    char wait = Serial.read();         
    //Signal.concat(wait);
    
    if ( wait == '\n') {
      //Serial.print("I receved : ");
      //Serial.println(Signal);
      //Setpoint = Signal.toInt();
      //Signal = "";
    }
  }
  Serial.println(counter);   
  counter = counter+1;
  delay(500);
}
```

this is simple code.

When I use the USB serial port, it works fine regardless of the terminal input.[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jhg6.png)

But when I use Rx,Tx pin for HC-06, it works not fine.(It works fine before when I send data from my smartphone.)[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjbVk.png)

What do I need to fix to run it like when using the usb port???????????

Answer (score 0):

Tx & Rx are using same pins the USB port is using for the `serial.print` command.
So it creates a contention.
Try commenting out all `Serial.print` commands.

Comment: I don't use usb data lines when I testing bluetooth module(hc-06) because my usb line have not datalines.

Comment: @SON: The TX & RX are hard wired , so when you do "Serial.println(counter)", it toggles the TX & RX are being toggled, so influencing the HC-06. So you could try commenting out the Serial.println .